# Which world is each playable character from?

Tags: chrono-cross

I'm playing Chrono Cross for the first time. I'm on Disc 2; I've just beaten Fate and had the Terra Tower rise into the air.

Chrono Cross is the first RPG I've played where I really, really feel like I should have been taking notes the whole time. In particular, I'm having a terrible time trying to keep the two worlds separate in my mind, *especially* the origins of each playable character I've picked up. I know that very interesting things happen when you take a character to his counterpart or his loved ones in the opposite world, but am frustrated when I can't find one and am not sure whether I'm in the correct world.

I've tried looking at various lists, [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chrono_Cross_characters), etc. But they don't always specify which world the *playable* version comes from, and they very often include spoilers that I don't want to read.

So: can anyone provide **a succinct, spoiler free list of each playable character and which world they come from**?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: Thanks for the edit (not sarcastic). I knew the standard practice was to put the game's name in the tags and not the post title, but I didn't know it was a hard and fast rule. I broke with the tradition because this seems to be the first Chrono Cross question on the site, and I thought it needed a little extra emphasis. But that was poor reasoning, really, so thanks.

Comment: Question... How important is it that they be spoiler tagged or omitted? Because, honestly, I can't remember who you would have met up to this point.

Comment: Any good answer to this will include a complete list of playable characters, which is obviously a spoiler.

Comment: ...I will say it looks like all this info is on the Chrono Wikia and also on RPG Classics, but not in a convenient chart, and I don't want the upvotes enough to write it out... xD

Comment: @Fluttershy Not that important. Only put that there in case someone came along who REALLY knew the game and would know off the top of their head.

Comment: @Shinrai I know the information is elsewhere, but I want the info without any more storyline spoilers than are implicit in the character list itself. I've already been spoiled that Dario is still alive while seeking an answer.

Comment: @Fluttershy and all: I've edited the question; it now specifies exactly which characters I'm aware of.

Comment: Frankly, I think that putting part of the answer list in a spoiler as suggested should not happen because no part of the substance of the question is dependent on where in the story you are. Spoilering based on who asked the question simply does not make sense. Also, "suggested formatting" is implied by the question and as stated is suboptimal, as the answer shows. As such, I think everything after the question mark is irrelevant to the question and I am removing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each character's Origin can be found [on this site](http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/psx/cc/characters.shtml), including more detailed information (Weapon, Element Grid, Innate, how to recruit, etc.). They are as follows:

- Doc (**Another**)
- Draggy (**Another**)
- Fargo (**Another**)
- Funguy (**Home**)
- Glenn (**Another**)
- Greco (**Another**)
- Grobyc (**Unknown**)
- Guile (**Another**)
- Harle (**Another**)
- Irenes (**Home**)
- Janice (**Home**)
- Karsh (**Another**)
- Kidd (**Unknown**)
- Korcha (**Another**)
- Leah (**Home**)
- Leena (**Another**)
- Lucia (**Another**)
- Lynx (**Home**)
- Masha (**Another**)
- Marcy (**Another**)
- Mel (**Another**)
- Miki (**Home**)
- Mojo (**Another**)
- NeoFio (**Another**)
- Nikki (**Another**)
- Norris (**Home**)
- Orcha (**Another**)
- Orlha (**Another**)
- Pierre (**Another**)
- Pip (**Another**)
- Poshul (**Home or Another**)
- Radius (**Home**)
- Razzly (**Home**)
- Riddel (**Another**)
- Serge (**Home**)
- Skelly (**Another**)
- Sneff (**Home**)
- Sprigg (**Dimension Vortex**)
- Starky (**Another Planet**)
- Steena (**Home**)
- Turnip (**Home**)
- Van (**Home**)
- Viper (**Another**)
- Zappa (**Home**)
- Zoah (**El Nido**)

That is the complete list of 45 playable characters. It is worth noting, however, that you cannot recruit every single one of them in a single playthrough. For example, there is a point where the story line will branch, forcing you to choose between two groups of three.

Those groups are:

> Korcha, Razzly, and Mel

or

> Macha, Glenn, and Doc

Comment: There are some other characters that are mutually exclusive - I seem to recall having to choose between Pierre, Nikki, and Guile at the very least.

Comment: @Shinrai Noted. Hopefully my subtle edit will fix any confusion. Thanks!